# How the determine the number of real positive roots of a polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, roots, symbolic-computation

**The Problem**

> For a polynomial (of degree 3 or 4) with real coefficients how can we determine the number of real positive roots?

or phrased a different way

> What conditions enure that a polynomial (of degree 3 or 4) with real coefficients has 0,1,2,3,or 4 positive real roots?

**Context**

I have a set of polynomials which have complicated coefficients which consists of [several constants](https://imgur.com/a/oJ7uP). I can determine the conditions when these coefficients are positive or negative. I am interested in only the positive real roots of these polynomials.

**Possible Theorems to Use**

Use a combination of [Descartes' rule of signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs), and [Rolle's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle%27s_theorem)?

**Notes**

- These posts with similar titles [Number of real positive roots of a polynomial?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/451077/number-of-real-positive-roots-of-a-polynomial) [Number of real positive roots of a polynomial?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/451077/number-of-real-positive-roots-of-a-polynomial) as the polynomials in these questions have numbers as their coefficients (rather than unknown constants) or have a specific structure.
- I am not interested in finding the explicit roots to these polynomials. I can solve them using Mathematica and other computer algebra systems. Determining when the roots are positive and real is the real problem.
- I am not sure what tags to use for this post, suggestions and edits are welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you want is
Sturm's theorem:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem

This gives a method
of computing 
the number of real roots
of a polynomial
in any interval
of the real line.